# ChartJs in ionic Framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, chart.js

I am woriking with ionic and try to building a simple pie with Chart.js.
I have tried a lot of things but  the pie never shows up.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400" />
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
console.log('ctx', ctx)
window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Ionic Framework then you should also be using AngularJS. If that is so then you would need to include the dependency in your controller. I used ChartJS in my project very easily. Post your controller javascript code and I can help you setup. Take a look at this link first:

https://github.com/gonewandering/angles

You need to include the files in your index.html file first:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1-beta.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="angles.js"></script>
```

Then include "angles" as a dependency:

```
var app = angular.module("anglesExample", ["angles"]);
```

Everything else appears to be okay.

Best of luck!

Comment: I wanted to comment that the biggest problem I've had with ionic and charts is that anytime I try to add a charting dependency via ionic/bower angular breaks. Since angles is very light on the dependencies I am able to use it without breaking angular in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use another chart generator, something like:

[angular-charts](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts/)

This was built to work with angular...as Ionic was.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chart.js, make sure you add the reference to your app.js

```
angular.module('yourapp', ['ionic', 'chart.js']);
```

Besides, you also need to include the following in your index.html, of course you have to make sure you are pointing to the correct directory where you put the 3 files below.

```
<!-- CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-chart.css">
<!-- Library files -->
<script src="angular.chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

best responsive chart for ionic framework

https://market.ionic.io/themes/charts